# Putty to windows from windows

Tags: windows, putty

This could be naive. I would like to know if I can putty to windows from any other OS(assume windows/linux). Succeeded to putty Linux from windows.

Comment: You can run remote PowerShell but a standard cmd would require some additional tools... Windows wasn't really built for this as it more relies on its GUI... additionally, it can be done... http://hindenes.com/trondsworking/2012/05/17/run-powershell-through-ssh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PuTTY is only a client program that you can use to connect using a variety of protocols, for example SSH. You don't "PuTTY into system", you "SSH into system" using PuTTY as a client.

If you want to access another system's console remotely, you have to install appropriate server on that machine. I recommend SSH as it's secure, efficient and commonly used.

I am using [KpyM Telnet / SSH Server](http://www.kpym.com/2/kpym/index.htm) for this purpose. Just be careful to configure it for SSH, not for Telnet. The latter one is insecure.

Comment: Thanks gronostaj. This cleared my doubt. Now I can ssh into another  windows machine

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The (telnet/SSH/SFTP/*etc.*) session you are creating with PuTTY is not dependent on the operating system.